# Track Users of my Software (PHP)

Tags: php

I am building a script people can download and run on their server, but I want to track installs and how many people are using it.

I came up with the idea to edit a text file on a central server and increment the number up per install, but this is flawed as anybody could edit the file by viewing the source.

I then thought I could use CouchDB with the RESTful API but again, people could cause damage outside it's intended purpose.

Then I thought Google Analytics, but this probably doesn't work on scripts on more than one computer.

Does anybody have any kind of solution for this?

Comment: Why not update the value in a database instead of a text file?

Comment: Make a "register" page and direct them to it. Nothing's 100% but you'll get a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a download counter to track downloads

also

direct users to a "thanks for installing" webpage on successful installation and track hits.